# m4: how to output literal $0?

Tags: m4

How does one avoid `m4` interpreting a `$0`, for example?

```
# foo.m4
define(`m4_foo',`$0')

# bar.txt
m4_foo
```

M4 does not replace the text.  There must be some way to deposit `$0` in a file via macros?

Answer (score 2):

Read through the docs, and the answer is:

```
define(`m4_foo',`$`'0')
```